# How to Get Data From IEnumerable <model>?

Tags: sql, ienumerable

New to IEnumerable, i have 2 query using sql and i try using IEnumerable to store data temporary. i want to get data from the first query for the next query.

Example, Q1 the output is "X", so the "X" is use as parameter for query 2.

the problem is i dont know how to get the data from Q1 correctly.

```
IEnumerable<DataQ1> data2 = null;
data2 = GetDataQ1(id, id2, id3, id4);
//inside GetDataQ1 is the method that return Query Q1


var x  = data2.'get column id from Q1';
//the result should be x = Q1.id;
```

i try `data2.FirstOrDefault().id` and return error  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

i still dont understand `FirstOrDefault()` is right method or no.

**Q1 Model**

```
public class DataQ1
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

**Q1 Query**

```
IEnumerable<DataQ1> GetDataQ1(string id, string id2, string id3, string id4)
    {
        ICollection<DataQ1> data;
        var strQuery = "The Query";
        using (var dbConn = new OracleConnection(Constr))
        {
            dbConn.Open();
            data = dbConn.Query<DataQ1>(strQuery).OrderBy(t => t.id).ToList();
            dbConn.Close();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Sorry for bad English. Any comment are very grateful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the implementation for 'GetDataQ1'.

But based on the error you receive, data2 is **null** on your call to `FirstOrDefault()`. Thus, the list you try to iterate was never initialized with a value.

Comment: thank you for answer. can you do explain like step by step that i have to do? is the `FirstOrDefault()` is right method to get the data?

Comment: In your `GetDataQ1`, you give 4 ids to the function but don't do anything with them. Are you sure yu're calling your query properly? You also don't need to close your connection, since you create it with `using`. Which oracle connection do you use? Maybe reference this example for retrieving data: [using commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: i get it, using `foreach (var par in data2)` returning the last id. now i should make a specific condition to get single id. Thanks.